# JTextField doesn't show when the Paint method is overridden

Tags: java, swing, paint, jtextfield

I'm writing a simple color chooser in java and I added a few `JTextFields` to get user input. I added the text fields to a `JPanel`, but for some reason, they don't appear when I override the paint method. When I run the program without overriding the paint method, though, the text fields show up. I know that they exist though, since the cursor changes when I hover over them, and if I add tool tip text, it shows up too. How do I get the text fields to show up?
Here is the code:

```
public class ColorSlider extends JPanel {
private ColorChooser parent;
private int sliderX = 0;
private JTextField textField = new JTextField();


    public ColorSlider(ColorChooser parent, int x, int y, String toolTip) {
            this.parent = parent;
            parent.add(this);
            setBounds(x, y, 96, 16);
            setVisible(true);
            setOpaque(false);
            setFocusable(true);
            addMouseListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
            setToolTipText(toolTip);
            setLayout(null);
            textField.setBounds(80, 0, 16, 16); // Yes, I know this is way too small
            textField.setText("Text");
            add(textField);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(new Color(0xDDDDE1));
            g.fillRect(0, 4, 80, 8);
            g.setColor(new Color(0x444448));
            g.fillRect(sliderX, 0, 8, 16);
    }
```

Comment: I fixed this by adding `paintChildren(g);` to the paint method, but any better solutions are welcome.

Comment: If you overrode `paint` and then called `paintChildren`, you've just made it significantly worse.  You should not be overriding `paint`, but instead should be using `paintComponent` and calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting. This and a better solution was presented in my answer...

Comment: *"I'm writing a simple color chooser in java.."*  `JColorChooser` is relatively simple to [use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html)..

Comment: I know, but I'm writing something specific to my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Essentially what you've done is broken the paint chain.  Painting is made up of a series of chained method calls, each method adding something to the process, background, border, children...etc.

By overriding `paint` and failing to call `super.paint`, you've prevented the panel from painting it's children.

Now, you could override `paintComponent` instead (ensuring that you call `super.paintComponent`), you could still end up with issues, as the painting is done behind the child components.

A better (and simpler) solution would be to create two `JPanel`s and use there `background` color properties to simply change the color as you need.

Don't use `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern GUI design, you don't control how the rendering works on different platforms, in particular how fonts are rendered.

Make use of [appropriate layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

**Additional...**

Separate the areas of responsibility.  The "slider" is responsible for ... sliding.  Create a component which does nothing but provides that functionality.  Then create another component which uses this slider and a `JTextField` to introduce extended functionality...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ColorSliderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ColorSliderTest();
    }

    public ColorSliderTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ColorSliderPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ColorSliderPane extends JPanel {

        private final ColorSliderControl colorSliderControl;
        private final JTextField field;

        public ColorSliderPane() {
            field = new JTextField(5);
            colorSliderControl = new ColorSliderControl();
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(colorSliderControl);
            JPanel filler = new JPanel();
            filler.add(field);
            add(filler, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

    public class ColorSliderControl extends JPanel {

        private int sliderX;

        public ColorSliderControl() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Insets insets = getInsets();
            int width = 80 + (insets.left + insets.right);
            int height = 16 + (insets.top + insets.bottom);
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            Insets insets = getInsets();

            int y = getHeight() / 2;
            int x = insets.left;
            int width = getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);

            g.setColor(new Color(0xDDDDE1));
            g.fillRect(x, y - 4, width, 8);

            g.setColor(new Color(0x444448));
            g.fillRect(sliderX + x, y - 8, 8, 16);

        }
    }

}
```

Before you say "but I want the field to the right", change

```
add(filler, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

to

```
add(filler, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

I might also mention [`JSlider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you've painted over them.

This is a singularly awful way to treat your UI code; just what is it you are trying to accomplish by having two rectangles with hard-coded colors at hard-coded positions in your panel?

Comment: Okay, but how do I fix it? I tried repainting the text fields in the paint methods, but that doesn't fix it. I hard coded in the rectangles because this is a slider object, and the rectangles are the bar and the slider, which I want to remain the same size.